# Databind custom items of RecyclerView to methods of ViewModel

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm using a MVVM pattern with Android Data Binding Library.

I have a RecyclerView with custom xml items bound to a ObservableArrayList in my ViewModel.

Within my custom xml items I have two ImageButtons I'd like to databind to methods within my ViewModel.

I have tried the following

Within my ViewModel class i have an extra class

```
public class Handlers {
    public void onClickTest(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Which I tried to use within my custom recyclerview XML items like this

```
<data>
    <variable name="handlers" type="package.names.MyViewModel.Handlers"/>
</data>
```

And

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btn_increase"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/btn_increase"
android:onClick="@{handlers::onClickTest}"/>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:onClick="@{handlers.onClickTest}"

public void onClickTest(View view) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onClickTest() called with: view = [" + view + "]");
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```